# Magento - percentage discount for shipping

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules, discount

I'm looking for extension or way how to set up cart price rule in magento. I need to set up 100% discount on shipping when total price of cart is higher then.. Why I need this? Because I'm using function which calculate (maximum) shipping distance by google matrix api.
Does anybody know how to do it? I have seen some shipping extension where I would be able to do it but it costs 99$ and it too much since I use just this one little function.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Please use promotions - shopping cart rules. And set up free shipping discount type for your cart conditions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I'm unable to set percentage discount only for shipping. I can set it as percentage discount for products price but not for shipping. Am I missing someting?

Comment: Set amount to zero and select the free shipping option at the same form.

Comment: With this solution I can set free shipping, that's true but I need to set discount for my regular shipping method because I need to check if customers are in our 10 km distance area or not, my extension does by google api matrix..